# Transpiling CSS class names in a react component is not working properly

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, css-loader

I have a react app where I have the following component:

`component.js`

```js
import styles from './styles.css';

const SomeComponent = (props) => {
    return <div className={`${styles["container"]}`}>Hey :D</div>
}

export default SomeComponent;
```

`styles.css`

```css
@value container: #f5f5f5;

.container {
    background-color: red;
}
```

The `styles["container"]` should return the transpiled name of the CSS class `container`. Right now is returning an empty object.

All of this was working perfectly fine until I updated some dependencies for my project. In our company we had really old dependencies, so we decided to update them.

#### Old configuration (with this it worked)

- [Webpack config](https://gist.github.com/antoniogamizbadger/1a97491d06ac6efd8b6823ef7f1dffe5)
- [Package.json](https://gist.github.com/antoniogamizbadger/508fd17eedf13a5ffa6ae1f4f7ba27da)
- Running on node 11.0.0.

#### New configuration (with this everything works except what I described earlier)

- [Webpack config](https://gist.github.com/antoniogamizbadger/5aab52cae2b89b30d16b5ead88ca9cb9#file-new_webpack-js)
- [New package.json](https://gist.github.com/antoniogamizbadger/f6eb1a5c5f332f6c29306a7929701326)
- Running on node 14.17.3.

#### More info

I know that this is not a reproducible example, but I have not been able to create one. I cannot even install the dependencies alone to isolate the problem.

I have made some digging and I think the problem has to be in this part of the webpack configuration. Or maybe is having the same name for a variable and for a class. I have just realised that it works perfectly for class names with different names than values.

```js
test: /\.css$/,
exclude: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@material'),
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/@rmwc'),
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-dual-listbox/lib/react-dual-listbox.css'),
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-image-lightbox/style.css'),
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'web/js/src/modules/Common/styles/material.css'),
],
use: [
    { loader: 'style-loader' },
    {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
            importLoaders: 1,
            modules: { localIdentName: '[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]' },
        },
    }],
},
```

In the [documentaion of the css loader module](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#object-2) I found the option `namedExport: true`, but I cannot use it becuase that appears in the version `6.2.9` and I'm using `3.6.0` (previously I was using `2.1.1`).

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried renaming the CSS file to `styles.module.css`? I think the `.module.css` part is essential

Comment: I have just tried that and it does not work :(

Comment: You need brackets around className={`${styles["container"]}`}, not sure if related

Comment: Yeah, my mistake writing the question. They are written in my code.

Comment: I have made an update with my new finding. It works with class names that are unique inside my styles.css. That is, if I have a value and a class with the same name, it does not work for that case.